# Visual Studio Web Development - General Question?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I like using Visual Basic for C++. I'm a student

I noticed the web development feature in it, and I was wondering if it is any good for web design, maybe if someone has used it or does use it if they can give a few words on weather or not it's worth learning?

I have been using Dreamweaver as my platform for web design.

So pretty much I'm asking Dreamweaver VS Visual Studio for webdesign, pros and cons?

Comment: +1 for taking the initiative. You don't earn anything unless you try.

Comment: "Visual Basic for C++"? what's that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Dreamweaver toooooo much...  so I don't really have an opinion on it, other than I think it is a nice start for people new to web dev; for people more familiar with Dreamweaver I think someone else could give you a better opinion on its advanced features...

... but for VS - it's still my favorite development environment across all platforms, in every single aspect except for the web development feature!  I find it slow, I find that many times it won't render controls on my page or whatever - in saying this though, this is for ASP.NET MVC & Webforms development.  I haven't used it for static HTML development - I stick with Notepad++ or Geany (linux) for that kinda stuff.

You may find using VS for static page development may be very fast, and since you're familiar with Visual Studio for C++ then I think you'd find arranging your solution easier in VS.  When doing web dev in VS, I never use the design view, just stick to code.  If that has you at a disadvantage, or if you want decent WYSIWYG design, stick with Dreamweaver.  Sounds like you've been using it for longer for web dev anyway :)

Another pro with using VS is with VisualSVN is that you have integrated version control and if you're working on a big web project, this is veeery convenient. :)  I guess it just comes down to taste, and how well you utilize the features on each platform.

Answer (score 0):

Go for it. Try Visual Studio Express Edition to learn & practice for web/windows/phone & database applications. Microsoft gives it to you for free.

[Microsoft Express Home](http://www.microsoft.com/express/)